# Checkbox value is always 'on'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, checkbox

this is my checkbox

**HTML**

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input id="eu_want_team" name="eu_want_team" type="checkbox">
</label>
```

**JQuery**

```
var eu_want_team = $('#eu_want_team').val();
alert(eu_want_team);
```

Its always displaying ON, is it checked or not. Whats the problem with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've re-tagged as `jQuery`, assuming that's where `$()` and `val()` come from. Feel free to correct it if I was wrong. And next time you ask about a non-native JavaScript function don't forget to post its code or mention what library it belongs to.

Comment: u should use `.prop('checked')` in jQuery

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use `.is(':checked')` instead: **[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AB3eb/)**

```
var eu_want_team = $('#eu_want_team').is(':checked');
alert(eu_want_team);
```

or as @Itay said in comments you can use jQuery's `.prop()` to get the checked property value:

```
alert($("#eu_want_team").prop("checked"));
```

Comment: +1 . Or  `$("#eu_want_team").prop("checked")`

Comment: @Itay You're also right. will add to answer

Comment: when i alert using `.is(":checked");` i get false always

Answer (score 15):

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input id="eu_want_team" name="eu_want_team" type="checkbox" value="somevalue">
</label>

<script>
   var ele = document.getElementById("eu_want_team");
   if(ele.checked)
   alert(ele.value)

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work :

```
if ($('#element').is(":checked")) {
    eu_want_team = 1;
} else {
    eu_want_team = 0;
}
alert(eu_want_team);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a quick look at this answer for checking if a checkbox is checked.

[How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

But basically you want to do something like below to check its value:

```
if ($("#element").is(":checked")) {
  alert("I'm checked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you want to do

```
$("#eu_want_team").click(function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked')); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ( $('#element').is(':checked')){
    alert(element);
   }
```